# Form is submitting to an unexpected endpoint, even though asp-action is set correctly on the form element

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The first case works

In the second case, I made 2  changes from

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Delete">
```

to

```
<form method="post" asp-action="DeleteConfirmed">
```

and removing `[ActionName("Delete")]` and now the deletion fails.

## Case 1

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Delete">
     <input type="submit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"  value="Delete"  />                    
</form>

public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
  // intentionally removed for simplicity 
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Delete")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
  // intentionally removed for simplicity 
}
```

Rendered HTML before form posting:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Delete/3">

<input type="submit"  value="Delete"  formaction="/Home/Delete/3" />
```

## Case 2

```
<form method="post" asp-action="DeleteConfirmed">
     <input type="submit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"  value="Delete"  />                    
</form>

public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
  // intentionally removed for simplicity 
}

[HttpPost]
//[ActionName("Delete")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
  // intentionally removed for simplicity 
}
```

Rendered HTML before form posting:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/DeleteConfirmed">

<input type="submit"  value="Delete"  formaction="/Home/Delete/3" />
```

## Question

What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest setting `asp-action` of the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger form-control"
    asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-action="DeleteConfirmed"
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?');" 
/>
```

So it knows to submit to the correct POST endpoint.

This is necessary since you have set the `asp-route-id`, as per [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12649#issuecomment-517427333):

> When you add an asp-route-id on a submit button, it independently
>   determines the Action it would route to. It does not work in tandem
>   with the values you specified in form. If you're attempting to post to
>   two different actions from a single form, using the "working" sample
>   *(which is what I have suggested)* would be the way to go. Alternatively, specifying all the route values on
>   the form tag would be the way to go:

```
<form asp-action="DeleteConfirmed" asp-route-id="1">
<input type="submit" /> </form>
```

Comment: A good info: [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12649#issuecomment-517427333).

Comment: Thanks. I'll incorporate that into the answer.